# Working example of FormatLocalized ClaimsTransformation in Azure AD B2C custom policies?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Does someone have a working example of a ClaimsTranformation of type "FormatLocalizedString" in Azure AD B2C Custom policies ?

I know that this type exists (as it's in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#formatlocalizedstring)) but can't seem to find any example of the web (and of course, it doesn't work with me...).

More precisely, I try to use this transformation to manage the body of a SMS I send with Twilio. Is this even possible ? Can we use the Azure localization process like that ?

Thank you very much

The code I use is literally the code of the official documentation. When we are in the ClaimsTransformation, I know that the claim "email" has the correct value but the output claim "responseMsg" is empty.

Comment: Can you show your existing code?

Comment: The code I use is the one of the official documentation. I added a few information about the value of the input and output claims.